# Javascript random min max doesn't work

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to make a simple program for a tabletop game that calculates damage. So I want to use random between two integers with a couple of percentage stuff to calculate damage.

The problem is random doesn't work for me. It doesn't matter what numbers I set as min or max, it always starts from 0 to the number before max.

```
<script>
function showDiv() {
var armor = document.getElementById('armortype').value;
var damage = document.getElementById('dmgtype').value;
var min = document.getElementById('mindmg').value;
var max = document.getElementById('maxdmg').value;

document.getElementById('result').style.display = "block";
for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
{ 
var dmg_done = Math.floor(Math.random()*max+min+1);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += " " + dmg_done;
}

}
</script>
```

So for min = 3, max = 6 I get the following 100 numbers:

> 3 1 2 2 0 2 2 1 2 2 3 3 4 0 1 1 2 2 5 2 3 5 3 3 3 4 0 0 5 2 3 0 4 0 2 1 0 5 4 1 0 5 5 4 2 1 2 4 5 1 5 1 0 4 3 5 2 1 4 3 1 1 5 1 4 2 1 0 3 3 3 4 3 4 5 4 2 0 2 4 5 0 3 1 2 5 0 1 5 1 2 2 1 4 0 0 0 1 4 2

So it doesn't matter that min is 3, it randomizes from 0 and there is not even a single 6 in the result.

Comment: its value from a textbox, and i put 3 and 6 in the textboxes

Comment: `var min = 3;` and `var max = 6` instead of extracting the values from the text fields and see if that works to test whether it's the function or the values that are being taken from the text fields. The reason I say this is because many answers are including the right code, but you keep getting different results when you try those answers. I'm pretty sure the fifth and sixth lines of your posted code are not getting the right values for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo:**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/zprr6/

**You want to utilize it as such:**

```
var dmg_done = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
```

The reason it starts at 0, is because the `Math.random` function produces a float from 0-1 (as many `JS` functions and features do).

So, by telling it to start at `max - min + 1, ie 4`, it avoids using the `0` as a starting value.

Comment: What do you mean? The page doesn't open btw

Comment: It just loads forever.

Comment: And to explain, `Math.random` produces a value inbetween 0 and 1. `Math.floor` rounds down to the nearest integer. So if it comes up with `.6`, and it floors to `0`, then you start at `0` for your random function (instead of `1` as desired).

Comment: Well, it opens fine on my desktop version. What platform are you on?

Comment: Okay I guess its my internet. It opened and I saw it. Also I tried what you wrote and it actually worked. That only means that my min max values I get from the textboxes are somehow incorrect. Is it possible that they are string?

Comment: It's possible, but in all likelihood it's that the value itself is just wrong. Do you have a full fiddle I can see? Maybe I can find the bug.

Comment: Sure how to copy the entire HTML in jsfiddle?

Comment: You don't, you disect all the `HTML`y stuff (<head>, <body>, etc) and put your script in the javascript section.

Comment: Well nevermind, I found the problem, it was that strings were used not numbers that's why it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Math.floor(Math.random()*max+min+1)` with `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)`

Comment: I changed it and ran it again for 3 and 6. It gave me: 1 0 1 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 3 1 3 2 2 2 0 3 3 1 3 0 3 3 1 2 1 0 3 3 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 0 2 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 0 2 3 3 0 2 1 3 1 1 3 1 0 3 0 2 0 3 2 1 3 0 3 1 1 0 1 0 2 2 0 2 2 0 1 2 1 3 1 0 3 1 0 1 3 3 0

Comment: Try this code really quick. It worked for me, so I'm wondering if the fifth and sixth lines in your code are actually returning the right values: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JanrainRyland/10431120/raw/becc9ea3d8fd37d3075f548b3279f2fd00385bad/randomnumber

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you try calculating random like this

```
function getRandom (min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

Edit: to add to the comment

```
var valOne = $("#input-1").val(),
     valTwo = $("#input-2").val();

$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#answer-input").val(getRandom(parseInt(valOne), parseInt(valTwo)));
);
```

Comment: how to try this for a button click and two textboxes? what to put in the onclick="getRandom (??)"?

Comment: This is not a correct Random range function as it has an off by 1 bug. The correct logic is: `Math.floor( (Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min )`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * (max+1-min))+min);
```

max+1 - so that the maximum is include, and +min so that the min is respected

Test case

```
var max = 6;
var min = 3;

var result = "";
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
result += Math.floor((Math.random()*(max+1-min))+min) +",";

}
console.log(result);
```

results (5 runs)
3,4,5,6,6,4,5,6,3,5,5,3,5,5,6,6,5,4,5,5,4,5,6,6,6,5,6,3,4,3,5,3,6,6,6,3,6,3,5,6,5,4,6,6,6,5,5,4,3,5,6,6,3,6,6,3,6,5,6,5,6,5,3,3,5,6,6,4,5,5,4,3,5,4,4,4,3,5,4,5,5,3,3,4,4,6,3,3,3,4,4,3,6,3,4,4,3,3,4,6,

6,5,4,3,6,4,4,6,4,4,5,5,3,4,6,4,4,3,4,6,6,5,3,6,4,5,4,6,5,4,4,3,5,6,4,3,5,5,3,5,4,3,6,4,3,3,3,4,6,5,6,3,5,5,6,6,6,5,5,6,5,6,5,4,5,4,4,5,3,6,3,3,6,5,6,3,5,3,6,3,5,6,3,4,5,4,3,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,5,6,

3,3,6,5,5,3,3,4,3,5,6,4,3,3,6,3,6,6,3,4,5,5,5,4,4,6,6,3,3,3,5,4,4,3,6,6,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,3,6,3,5,4,5,6,3,6,5,3,3,4,5,4,6,3,4,6,3,6,3,4,6,5,3,6,3,5,6,5,6,4,5,4,3,6,4,4,3,4,6,3,5,5,3,6,6,6,5,6,6,4,3,6,3,4,

4,4,3,6,4,6,4,3,5,4,5,3,4,5,6,6,6,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,4,4,6,6,5,5,5,3,6,3,5,4,6,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,3,3,5,4,6,5,5,4,4,6,6,6,3,4,6,6,3,6,5,5,4,6,6,4,3,4,6,3,5,6,4,3,5,6,3,4,3,6,6,6,6,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,4,3,6,5,4,3,

4,5,3,6,3,4,5,4,4,5,5,3,3,6,6,4,6,4,5,5,3,5,5,5,3,6,3,5,4,5,5,6,6,4,4,5,3,3,4,5,5,5,4,6,5,4,5,4,5,6,6,3,3,3,4,3,4,6,5,3,5,5,3,3,5,6,3,5,6,3,6,3,5,5,5,6,3,6,4,3,4,5,5,3,6,6,6,6,4,5,6,5,3,4,4,3,4,6,3,6,

On an additional note, getting the value of a textbox always returns a string, so the following (min and max) are both strings

```
var min = document.getElementById('mindmg').value;
var max = document.getElementById('maxdmg').value;
```

I would check that they are actually numbers, and cast them, before using them in the Math, something like

```
var min = +(document.getElementById('mindmg').value);
var max = +(document.getElementById('maxdmg').value);
```

putting the + at the front will casue a number cast **IF IT CAN**, if it can't, it will be NaN (Not a Number), so before you use, check that they are not NaN. Nan can easily be checked, as nothing equala Nan not even Nan so something like

```
if(min === min && max === max)
{
    //... all good to use con..
}
```

will check that they are actually numbers as Nan will never equal NaN but 3 will always equal 3

Comment: Changed it and tried it for 3 and 6. I am getting: 24 22 39 21 47 43 4 7 40 7 37 22 55 45 20 32 36 8 41 41 53 26 55 0 36 39 53 52 60 42 44 38 17 39 19 4 52 13 35 6 6 7 27 10 57 14 29 29 39 31 46 27 46 36 58 24 12 12 18 3 21 10 55 54 49 15 37 53 49 7 47 16 48 13 54 5 4 2 56 14 58 7 34 26 5 39 38 42 24 54 15 28 35 29 34 28 21 47 11 59

Comment: Missed the -min from the top argument, so initial code was incorrect, corrected now. Intrigued as to how you got that sample numbers, as there would be no way to get a number above max + min, are you sure you ran it correctly , as I have run it quite a few times and get nothing in that sort of range.

Comment: I am still getting values like those above even with the changed. However I noticed that there is a problem with the values in min and max, its like they are strings not numbers

Comment: I have added some more to my answer

Comment: Found the problem. It was that min and max were used as strings, not ints. parseInt solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. both min and max were used as strings, not numbers. So I just parsed them as ints like this:

```
var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('mindmg').value);
var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('maxdmg').value);
```

and it works flawlessly now

Comment: I thought that would be the issue. Glad you got it resolved! :)